# param not found in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've made a little test with Rails scaffolding, and I tried to generate a controller and a view for an already existing model.

I'm trying to edit a value for my model.

In the controller all the requires methods are there, and there's even :

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def tag_params
    params[:tag]
end
```

The only value I tried to update from my model (named Tag) was :name, so I edited the `tag_params` method to look like this:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def tag_params
    params[:tag].require(:tag).permit(:name)
end
```

as I usually do, but now I get a `param not found: tag` exception.

However, if I write it like this

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def tag_params
    params[:tag].permit(:name)
end
```

it works alright. Why is that?

The form_for declaration in the view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@tag) do |f| %>
```

For those who don't know how scaffolding method look like in the controller, here's a part of it :

```
 # GET /tags/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tags/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tags/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tag.update(tag_params)
        format.html { redirect_to tags_path, notice: 'Tag was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @tag.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def tag_params
        params[:tag]
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:tag].require(:tag)` will require a param `tag` inside the `params[:tag]` hash. What you want to do is `params.require(:tag).permit(:name)`.

Comment: Is `params[:tag]` the same as `params.require(:tag)` ?

Comment: No, `params[:tag]` is the actual hash containing the attributes for the tag (ie name). `params.require(:tag)` is a way of requiring a tag parameter in the parameters hash.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
def tag_params
  params.require(:tag).permit(:name)
end
```